# scp'ing multiple files in one pass - to multiple destinations on one target server?

Tags: file-management, scp

I would like to scp about a half dozen files in a couple directories to the same directories on a target machine.

Without utilizing ssh keys, is this possible in one call?

For example:

```
scp /path/to/fileA,/anoth/erpath/to/fileB,/yet/more/files/*    #continue next line
    destination:/path/to,/anoth/erpath/to,/yet/more/files
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zip up the files on the sending side and unzip them on the receiving side.

```
tar -cf - /path/to/fileA /anoth/erpath/to/fileB /yet/more/files/* |
ssh -C destination 'cd / && tar -xf -'
```

You could also script an sftp session, or use rsync with the right filter.

Comment: if you only have a few files you have to copy in total than I appreciate the `scp -r` solution. but for more this is much faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy from multiple src to one destination. `scp -r src1 src2 ... dst`  But not to **multiple** destinations.

One option is to copy all the directory to a temp destination directory.  Then move them back afterwards.

Comment: this works as good as the tar-ssh solution. plus it is easier to type/remember. it also gives you feedback what is being uploaded. BUT if you have many little files to copy tar-ssh will be much faster, as it only has to transfer one big file, whereas scp-r copies each file individually with much more overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `pssh` package. It has `parallel-scp` command. `-h` option allows you to provide text file with multiple hosts as destination (one per line).

Comment: does this get around needing to ask for the passwords each time a file from A goes to B?

Comment: For that I am using `ssh-add`. You type your credentials once at the beginning of a day. Then you are logged in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to copy multiple files to multiple destinations.

> scp -r src{1,2,3} dest{1,2,3}

this command acts like the following set of commands

> scp -r src1 dest1
>
> scp -r src1 dest2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> scp -r src3 dest2
>
> scp -r src3 dest3

Comment: Doesn't work when I try. `ubuntu@landslide:~$ scp -r {test1,test2} landslide:/home/ubuntu/{test3,test4}`
`scp: /home/ubuntu/test4: No such file or directory` It wants the destination to be a directory.